# "Method App\Http\Controllers\API\UserController::show does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, server

I get a error "Method App\Http\Controllers\API\UserController::show does not exist.",…
[from my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKwNT.png)

> Router Code
>   [image]
>
> Controller Code
>   [image]

Comment: post your code here

Comment: override your last two routes over the resource route. Means paste your resource route after `/user/role` and `/user/roles` routes. Also it needs to be `apiResource` for `api.php` not just simple `resource`

Comment: Thank you. It's work fine now

Answer (score 0):

You dont have any method call 'show' in your controller 'UserController'. You need to rename your function in your controller or call the right function.

Comment: Please don't give answer if you are not sure about